# How does Urbanspoon display map?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mapkit

I've looked at Google's map API, which is all javascript and terribly slow on the iPhone.  I then tried using the link option available at maps.google.com.  That is fast but I can't see having much control over it.  It also displays a little search box at the top of the map.  Google's API says you must use maps in a website, which the iPhone isn't.  I'm not sure about licensing for maps.google.com.

Urbanspoon's scope option does everything I want with maps in regards to displaying nearby businesses based on your location.  Given the limited set of tools available for Google maps without mapkit, I don't know how they are doing it.  It looks as though they have somehow integrated with mapkit. Clicking an annotation shows the callout and another click pushes a new view with details from that pin.  Any ideas how this can be done?

-- EDIT --

Just to be clear, mapkit doesn't display surrounding businesses.  That's the crux of the problem and I'm not sure how Urbanspoon got past it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the Google AJAX Search API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/

It's a Javascript library, but for Flash, and other Non-Javascript environments, the API exposes a raw RESTful interface that returns JSON encoded results.

And within this API, what you want is the 'Local Search' if you are looking for nearby businesses based on the location.

Answer (score 0):

Urbanspoon probably gets the data for the locations of nearby businesses via some other method than the MapKit API.

Then its likely that they use the MapKit API to display custom MapKit Annotations at those locations.

Comment: "...via some other method...".  Right but who offers such a service? [As a side note, I wonder where the other response went]

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps Google has an API to get coordinates of places on a map?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about the Google Maps API for displaying maps (which you've already said is all javascript and slow on the iPhone). But perhaps there may be an API that simply returns the coords?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a business data provider you could look into yelp's [API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation).